# Running JavaScript in Microsoft Edge browser without installing a userscript manager like Tampermonkey

Tags: windows-10, script, javascript, browser-addons, microsoft-edge

I have a JavaScript script I desire to run each time I use Microsoft Edge; it should effect all webpages of a particular website.

It seems to me that naturally to do so I should install a [userscript manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript_manager) like Tampermonkey on Microsoft Edge and run the script through it, but that requires a Microsoft account and email which I don't want to have because I already have two Google accounts and emails which is enough heavy for me mentally.

Is there a way to run JavaScript script on Microsoft edge without installing a userscript manager?

Update - rleated: [Can I mirror all my Google Chrome extensions into Microsoft Edge in 19H2?](https://superuser.com/questions/1486232/can-i-mirror-all-my-google-chrome-extensions-into-microsoft-edge-in-19h2)

Comment: You are aware that in the very near future EdgeHTML will be retired for Chromium Edge right?  In fact it’s stable today, but the “final” release, won’t be until 19H2

Comment: Hello @Ramhound - I never heard any of these terms... Please consider expanding this a bit into an answer - thanks anyway...

Comment: I think I understand --- soon the Edge engine will change to be the same one of Chrome's and this will make the need to register for Microsoft for Edge extensions redundant... Well, that's nice, if it's a matter of days or 1 month, I think I can wait that...

Comment: Why not just create a local webpage with your script imported and run on that page? Then you set that document as your home page and voila... that would seem to achieve what you want.

Comment: @JohnDoea - EdgeHTML is the engine Edge currently uses.  Chromium Edge the replacement for EdgeHTML once it’s released.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, in great plea, please tell me in a comment, in your opinion / assessment, when should 19H2 version come out so I could install the extension without creating a Microsoft account (or "pump out" all current Tampermoneky scripts in chrome --- into Edge)? Thanks anyway...

Comment: 19H2 will be released in the second half of 2019

Comment: @Mokubai I totally misunderstand this approach --- you mean to create an HTML with a script tag containing my script and put it on some server I can manage? How would this catch to all web pages I visit on other websites. Please consider explaining this in an answer.

Comment: Oh and @Mokubai this might save me from waiting to 19H2 so in great plea, please write a short answer explaining what you mean exactly because I really misunderstand what you meant to.

Comment: @JohnDoea that was what I was meaning, but I don't know if it even might be a solution. All you say is that you need to run the script each time you run Edge, and I dont know if that just means you are happy to run it on it's own or whether it specifically needs to be injected into every page. I was hoping you would clarify your question to explain what the requirements were as it is currently ambiguous.

Comment: @Mokubai I just edited the question to try to better clarify what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Ramhound is changing the engine make all of us Windows10 users free from the need to make a Microsoft account to install Edge extensions? If not, then I'm not sure upgrading will suffice a solution.

Comment: @JohnDoea - You should install the current version of Chromium Edge and see if it will meet your needs.

Comment: @Ramhound you mean install it on Edge? Well, I'd have to learn how I do it first, if so... Thanks !

Comment: While you do need a Microsoft account that doesn't automatically mean that you *need* to use their email service too. You can create a Microsoft account using your Gmail email, and just not use your Gmail password (use a unique password)... All of the benefits of an account with only a single extra login. https://www.google.com/search?&q=create%20new%20microsoft%20account%20with%20gmail (I assume your problem is that you need to use the Microsoft Store to install extensions)

Comment: @Mokubai this entire management of Microsoft is something I don't want to take part in unless there is no other choice...

Comment: Without having a Microsoft email account, somehow Tmapermonkey was installed on Edge anyway... I don't know to explain why... But maybe it makes this entire question redundant and it know needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but it seems I had a false assumption in the question:

Without having a Microsoft email account, somehow Tmapermonkey was installed on Edge anyway... I don't know to explain how (I didn't recognize any install process on user interface).