# Can I mirror all my Google Chrome extensions into Microsoft Edge in 19H2?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, script, upgrade, microsoft-edge

I understood that after 19H2 upgrade for Windows 10, Microsoft's Edge engine will be changed from EdgeHTML to Blink (of Google Chrome).

For those using test versions of 19H2,
Can I "pump" all my Google Chrome extensions into Microsoft Edge in 19H2 instead re-installing all of them on Edge and re-configure each one on Edge?

<sub>This will save me from making each change in each extension on both browsers.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge has not yet changed although I have Edge with Chromium rendering running on Windows Insider (19H2) and the main browser applications are still different so what you want is not at all likely to work. Only the rendering engine is part of Edge. It otherwise looks and works the same as it did.

The applications are different enough so you would need to get your Edge Extensions from the Store